# How do I test a vue component that contains a v-text-field Vuetify child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I have an "EditableText" component that displays regular text that when clicked converts into a vuetify v-text-input component (kind of like trello's functionality when you edit the title of a card).

```
<template>
  <div class="editableText">
    <div v-if="!editMode" @click="editMode = true" class="editableText__text" :class="textClass">
      {{ this.value }}
    </div>
    <v-text-field
      v-else
      class="editableText__input no-label"
      :class="textClass"
      :value="value"
      :autofocus="true"
      :height="20"
      :single-line="true"
      :hide-details="true"
      @input="handleInput"
      @blur="editMode = false"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false
    }
  },

  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    textClass: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    handleInput(value) {
      this.$emit('input', value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

All of my unit tests for this component are working fine except for when I try to confirm that the EditableText component emits an input event when the VTextField child component fires an input event.

(most tests are omitted for length)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import vuetify from 'vuetify'
import EditableText from '@/components/EditableText'

Vue.use(vuetify) // temporary until vuetify/createLocalVue bug is resolved

const build = options => {
  return shallowMount(EditableText, options)
}

// Default props
let options
beforeEach(() => {
  options = {
    propsData: {
      value: 'Test value'
    }
  }
})

describe('EditableText', () => {
  it('emits an input event when the text input is changed', () => {
    const { VTextField } = Vue.options.components
    const wrapper = build(options)
    wrapper.find('.editableText__text').trigger('click') // need to click text to get VTextField to render
    wrapper.find(VTextField).trigger('input')
    expect(wrapper.emitted('input').length).toBe(1) // wrapper.emitted('input') is undefined
  })
})
```

Unfortunately the wrapper never ends up emitting the input, even though the component works completely fine when testing in the browser.

Is this something I should be testing and if so how should I go about testing that the EditableText component is emitting an input event properly? I've tried calling the handleInput method directly but couldn't find a way to do so.

I'd also like to write a test that tests how it handles an input of an empty string. Is there a way to test an input event with a specific value?

Comment: I would recommend you to test if when clicked "EditMode" is set to "True", if it's okay, save your input like -> const field = wrapper.find('.editableText__input'), 
try to check if it actually exists -> expect(field.exists()).toBe(true), after that try to manually set a value to your element -> field.element.value = 'a'   and see if the event is emitted, gl!